# Deleted my hosts file in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I managed to "accidentally" delete my hosts file stored in `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc` but can't create a new file and don't know how I should fix this issue. Also I get an error message saying i'm not allowed to create a new one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new hosts file with default contents, follow these steps, which are derived from the instructions labeled "Method 2" on [this Microsoft support page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/how-can-i-reset-ms-host-files-in-windows-8/4057335b-6160-4073-aafb-4412db9db971).
(Note: you have to be logged in as administrator.)

1. Open the Run dialog window by pressing <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Open the `system32` folder by typing "system32" in the Run window.
3. Browse to the `drivers` folder and then browse to `etc` folder.
4. In the `etc` folder, right-click on an open space (in the `System32\Drivers\Etc` folder), point to New, click Text Document, type `hosts`, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Click Yes to confirm that the file name extension will not be `.txt`.
6. Open the new Hosts file in a text editor.
   For example, open the file in Notepad, with administrator privileges.
7. Copy the following text to the file:

> # Copyright (c) 1993-2006 Microsoft Corp.
> #
> # This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
> #
>
> # This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
> # entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
> # be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
> # The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
> # space.
> #
> # Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
> # lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
> #
> # For example:
> #
> #      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
> #       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
> # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
> #       127.0.0.1       localhost
> #       ::1             localhost

But you have to open the Editor in which you edit the new hosts file as administrator (right-click --> Run As Administrator).

Comment: Please include pertinent information directly in your answer, to avoid possible future link-rot.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation. Though there is no need to copy the lines which are prefixed with a hash (`#`). So you can skip the copying and do it just a tad faster.

Comment: Yes. Its really annoying, that i had to prefix each hash with a \. But he wanted to have the original hosts-file. And that is the original host file. But i know what you mean.